# Why does jQuery.css('width') return different values in different browsers?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I've written some jQuery code that reads the width of the columns in a table and applies them to another table.

On my page, there is a TABLE like this:

```
<table style='table-layout:fixed;'>
     <tbody id='myTableBody'>
         <tr>
             <td style='width:100px;'>foo</td>
             <td style='width: 40px;'>bar</td>
         </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

I've written the following jQuery code to read the css width properties of this table:

```
var colWidths = [];
var cells = $('#myTableBody').find('td');
for (i = 0; i < cells.length; i++)
    colWidths.push($(cells[i]).css('width'));
```

After the code runs, I would expect `colWidths` to be `[100, 40]`, and in FireFox, it is.  However, in IE8, it is `[92,32]`.  This breaks my page in IE that depends on the values being correct.

I believe that it may be pertinent that my table is contained within a jQuery-ui-tabs element, and I know that the jQuery-ui css can do weird things, so I wouldn't be surprised if this has something to do with it.

Why is it that jQuery.css('width') doesn't return the value I expect in IE8?  What can I do about it?

Comment: I get 100 and 40 in IE8: http://jsfiddle.net/QhXjS/

Comment: Is your page a valid HTML 4.01 page? Maybe you've triggered the [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html) in IE8.

Comment: Thanks, @Rob W.  I'm betting that there is something on my page that is somehow causing me to get the wrong value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JQuery normalizes browser handling in this situation via `$().width()`.

`css("width")` is a different attribute / property that is not normalized but instead it retrieves the CSS value for the element(s).  `width()` is the "actual size in the dom" but doesn't take padding and margins where applicable into consideration where `css("width")` only retrieves the CSS value. As others have mentioned below this answer, `.outerWidth()` will do what `.width()` accomplishes, but **includes** padding and margins as represented by the native browser.

In short:

```
$(this).width() != $(this).css("width")
```

A good parallel example is this:

```
$(this).css("width")
```

is closer to

```
$(this).attr("name")
```

than `$(this).width()` or `$(this).height()`.

**Edit:**

Here is something I just tabbed over and saw that also illustrates the difference:

```
$(this).css("height", "auto");
alert($(this).height());
```

The alert will be a numeric value (pixels).

Comment: In that case, what can I do in order to retrieve the actual CSS 'width' value?

Comment: do you actually need the "CSS" value of width? Or the actual size in the client browser window? $(this).width() is "what the actual, visible element width looks like, in the native browser"

Comment: Using `.outerWidth()` gives the same result on both browsers!

Comment: returning to this much later - do not habitually lean on `outerWidth()`, while likely it will be a preserved feature of the jquery interface, its important to understand what coding practices you are entertaining to force the requirement of this function. 

TL:DR = don't solve this sort of issue "after the fact" unless entirely necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem trying to detect the width of the body and load specific scripts and I worked around it this way. May help you as well.

```
$('body,html').css({'overflow':'hidden'});
var width = $('body').width();
$('body,html').css({'overflow':''});
```

this gives a consistent value in all major browsers

`