# jQuery Get Height of Responsive Image

Tags: jquery

I have a set of images that are responsive to the page (i.e. max-width set to 100% ).

```
<div class="exh">
   <img src="#" />
</div>
<div class="exh">
   <img src="#" />
</div>
<div class="exh">
   <img src="#" />
</div>
```

with

```
.exh img {
   max-width:100%;
}
```

How do I retrieve the height of the image after the window is resized and whenever the page is loaded? When I use the following, I get a height of 0.

```
$(".exh img").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    console.log( $this.height() );
});
```

Comment: Did you actually load pictures into those image tags when you tried that? An empty img tag would have the calculated height of 0. I assume you did, I'm just asking to make sure because these kind of mistakes do happen.

Comment: Yes there are actually images haha! I just put nothing in there for example purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

per this answer I gave to a similar question :

[Why does jQuery.css('width') return different values in different browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9608642/why-does-jquery-csswidth-return-different-values-in-different-browsers/9608677#9608677)

`.width()` or `height()` is the "rendered in the DOM" size of the element - and for it to return a value greater than 0, the element needs to be fully available to the DOM ( aka the image needs to be fully loaded )

What you want is :

```
var myImage= new Image();
myImage.onload=function() { alert(this.height);}
myImage.src= "your/image/url";
```

In short - you need to guarantee that the image has loaded before you call `height()`

Answer (score 5):

If you need to do it whenever the page is loaded and when the page is resized do this:

```
$(document).ready( function() { //Fires when DOM is loaded
    getImageSizes();
    $(window).resize(function() { //Fires when window is resized
        getImageSizes();
    });
});
function getImageSizes() {
    $(".exh img").each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        console.log( $this.height() );
    });
}
```

More Info on .resize(): http://api.jquery.com/resize/

More Info on .ready(): http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: I don't think this was his actual question - his problem as it appears is that height() returns 0 when he is not expecting it.

Comment: It essentially is the same answer I gave - only to the extent that it is native Jquery rather than vanilla javascript. The concept remains the same tho : the request for `height()` occurs before the image loads.

Comment: Except I provided event references for the DOM being ready and for the window being resized, which is what he was asking for.