# jQuery Height of Responsive Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to get the height of the responsive image (width:100%) to adjust size of my DIV dynamically.. Following the post here

[jQuery Get Height of Responsive Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10422451/jquery-get-height-of-responsive-image)

the code below shows the ACTUAL height of the image, not the height of the image in CURRENT state, I mean if the DIV width is 200px the image is automatically resized accordingly, so the height... but the code below reports the actual image height.. how can I get the height of the image in current height (automatically resized) of the image... thanks for your time..

```
 var myImage= new Image();
 myImage.onload=function() { alert(this.height);}
 myImage.src= "your/image/url";
```

Comment: Why not wrap the image in a `<div>` with no margin, padding, or border, then use that to retrieve the height?

Comment: Thanks desertly, actually thats already wrapped, but it doesnt seem to set the height of DIV.. here is my current code..

$("#fi-container").height($("#theimage").height());

Comment: Please use http://jsfiddle.net/ to provide an example of your issue. Without knowing what these elements are, it is impossible to tell you exactly what's going wrong.

Comment: Thanks Desertlvy, actually there was a type in the name of variable in my code :) which I didnt realise and wasted 1 hour.. it has been fixed.. cheers - thanks..

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry guys, there was a typo in my code, the name of variable, I have fixed it, so please dont put any effort into this.. thanks for your time.. cheers

Comment: You should probably mark this as answered, or closed.

Comment: Now sure how to do that.. I tried to click on the TICK button it says I can do it in 2 days...

Comment: You can either delete the question, or mark this as an answer.